# Weka training data from MySql database

Tags: mysql, weka

This is my second posting regarding weka usage(the first was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280072/weka-classification-and-predicted-class)). I succeeded in providing Weka with the training and the sample test data using the TextDirectoryLoader. Works great. Now I want to move this to production, so the data to be classified is retrieved from a mysql table. This is how I'm doing it:

```
    TextDirectoryLoader loader = new TextDirectoryLoader();
    loader.setDirectory(new File("c:/Users/Yehia A.Salam/Desktop/dd/training-data"));
    Instances dataRaw = loader.getDataSet();

    StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
    filter.setInputFormat(dataRaw);
    Instances dataTraining = Filter.useFilter(dataRaw, filter);

    // Create test data instances[this works, but the sample data now needs to come frm the db instead, see below]
    //loader.setDirectory(new File("c:/Users/Yehia A.Salam/Desktop/dd/test-data"));
    //dataRaw = loader.getDataSet();
    //Instances dataTest = Filter.useFilter(dataRaw, filter);

    InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
    query.setUsername("myusername");
    query.setPassword("mypassword");
    String sql = "SELECT d.desc FROM deals d WHERE d.j48 = 1";
    query.setQuery(sql);
    Instances dataTest = Filter.useFilter(query.retrieveInstances(), filter);

    // Classify
    J48 model = new J48();
    model.buildClassifier(dataTraining);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTest.numInstances(); i++) {
             dataTest.instance(i).setClassMissing();
             double cls = model.classifyInstance(dataTest.instance(i));
             dataTest.instance(i).setClassValue(cls);
             System.out.println(cls + " -> " + dataTest.instance(i).classAttribute().value((int) cls));

    }
```

Unfortunately this is not working, weka stops unexpectedly on this line:

```
Instances dataTest = Filter.useFilter(query.retrieveInstances(), filter);
```

So I guess my question would be how to transform this part

```
// Create test data instances[this works, but the sample data now needs to come frm the db instead, see below]
//loader.setDirectory(new File("c:/Users/Yehia A.Salam/Desktop/dd/test-data"));
//dataRaw = loader.getDataSet();
//Instances dataTest = Filter.useFilter(dataRaw, filter);
```

to an sql based data

```
InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
query.setUsername("myusername");
query.setPassword("mypassword");
String sql = "SELECT d.desc FROM deals d WHERE d.j48 = 1";
query.setQuery(sql);
Instances dataTest = Filter.useFilter(query.retrieveInstances(), filter);
```

Note that there is no problems in the database connectivity and I actuall get the right number of instance.

Appreciate the help, very close.

Comment: What's the stack trace of weka stopping "unexpectedly"? Did you investigate the output of `query.retrieveInstances()`?

Comment: Are you sure about your SQL: `SELECT d.desc FROM deals d WHERE d.j48 = 1`? I would have expected something like `SELECT d.desc FROM deals AS d WHERE d.j48 = 1`.

Comment: @JanEglinger tried adding the AS but with no luck, I checked the error on query.retrieveInstances(), its o = (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Hm, that looks like you try to access the second element of an array that contains only one instance. Can you check the return object of `query.retrieveInstances()`? And did you check that the input format set by `filter.setInputFormat(dataRaw);` acutally works with your SQL instances? Just some guesses...

Comment: @JanEglinger okay i splitted the lines to         
  Instances qdata = query.retrieveInstances();
  Instances dataTest = Filter.useFilter(qdata, filter);
and actually i'm getting one instance in the first line which is correct, but the outofboundexception happens on the second

Comment: @JanEglinger and the difference in the qdata when loading the data from the directory or sql is outlined in http://justpaste.it/weka-directory and http://justpaste.it/weka-sql

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses [TextDirectoryLoader](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader.html) class which is based on [Arff Files from Text Collections](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+files+from+Text+Collections). According to their help files

```
"Loads all text files in a directory and 
 uses the subdirectory names as class labels. 
 The content of the text files will be stored in a String attribute, 
 the filename can be stored as well."
```

See following [code](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+files+from+Text+Collections)

```
 double[] newInst = new double[2];
 newInst[0] = (double)data.attribute(0).addStringValue(files[i]);
 ....
 newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).addStringValue(txtStr.toString());
 data.add(new Instance(1.0, newInst));
```

As you can see this code want 2 attribute values to add your data set. But your sql provides only one attribute.

```
 String sql = "SELECT d.desc FROM deals d WHERE d.j48 = 1";
```

This may be reason for your problem "(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) " in the code newInst[1](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader.html) part. Weka can't find second attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I am very much a beginner myself, but just in case it is useful, you know there is a [DatabaseLoader](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/DatabaseLoader.html) class and a [DatabaseConverter](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/DatabaseLoader.html) interface?

Comment: You should explain how these classes and interfaces can solve the problem.